# Java Selenium -- Best option?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I just got accepted to my first internship as a CS major in college.
I am trying to compare which web automation tool I should use for this company's website.
Selenium seems to be the biggest one in the market from what I've seen- But I'm not sure how it compares to other similar web automation tools such as Bugzilla and Appium. What are you guys' opinion on web automation tools?

I've researched the above 3- Selenium, Bugzilla and Appium, but I want to get a feel from what real people have to say.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please note that your question elicits opinions and discussions, which is off topic.   Also, I didn't realize Bugzilla was a web-automation tool.

Comment: Appium is also Selenium, but the driver is for apps.  Bugzilla is a bug reporting system.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a small confusion in your comparison.

Selenium, Bugzilla, and Appium serve different purposes in the software testing process.

- **Selenium** is a widely used open-source framework for automating web browsers. It supports a large variety of PL like Java, Python, C#, etc. to automate interactions with web browsers.
- **Bugzilla** is not a web automation tool. It is a web-based general-purpose bug-tracking system and testing tool. Bugzilla helps software developers and quality assurance engineers keep track of outstanding bugs, issues, and new features in a software project. It doesn't automate web browsers but provides a collaborative platform for managing software issues.
- **Appium** is a tool for automating mobile applications (Android/IOS). It allows you to write tests (also with multiple PL) for native, hybrid, and mobile web applications. Appium is not typically used for web automation but focuses on mobile application automation.

There are a lot of different solutions on the market:
Selenium, Playwright, Cypress, Puppeteer, TestCafe, WebdriverIO, Katalon Studio, NightwatchJS, Protractor and so on.

When choosing a web automation tool you should consider a lot of things. Some of them:

- the PL your company use. If all your codebase is on Java, there is not much sense in doing automation with Python or JS.
- browser support. Do you need to automate a lot of browser engines? If yes, then for example Puppeteer (for firefox/safari), or Playwright (for safari) would not be the best choice.
- costs. While most automation tools are free/open-source, you can still go for the paid solution like Katalon Studio.
- maturity of the tool. Do you want to work with a well-tested solution with a big community and good support, or do you prefer modern tools with fancy features, but limited community and support?

Although **Playwright** and **Cypress** are quite popular nowadays, I'd recommend you start with **Selenium** (after nailing the core, check the Selenium wrapper called **Selenide** (for Java) or **Selene** (for Python)), as it is indeed a popular, well-tested, and powerful choice with a huge community and a good variety of PL you can use. 
And from my point of view, if you are going to work with web automation, you just must be familiar with Selenium.